# What was Apollo's reason for siding with the Trojans?

Tags: greek, trojan-war, apollo, daedalus

It doesn't make sense to me. After the rebellion by Poseidon, Hera, Athena and Apollo, Poseidon and Apollo were sent to Troy as mortals to build a wall. When they finished, Troy's king refused to honor them. This caused angst between them. Then, Cassandra refused to honor her agreement with Apollo (I give you gift of prophecy and you give me virginity/sex).

This is two reasons why Apollo would side against the Trojans, so why didn't he? Does it have anything to do with Iapyx (a favorite of Apollo) being with the Trojans?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, first of all, Apollo is actually pretty neutral in the beginning of the war, very much like Zeus. It's after Zeus orders him to go get involved that he enters the war. Zeus secretly favored the Trojans, and hence he sent Apollo to help them. Apollo did that.
But we can't deny that Apollo did that just because Zeus asked him to. First of all, Apollo doesn't like Achilles. During the war, Achilles had killed a son of Apollo in spite of Thetis giving the clear warning: "Don't kill him. If you do, you'll be killed by Apollo." But of course, Achilles ignores and kills Tenes. So it's natural that Apollo would be against Achilles.
Also, Apollo has 2 sons of his fighting for Troy. One is Troilus, and the other is Hector (who is Apollo's son according to some poets). So obviously he'd favor Troy.

Answer (score 0):

Hecuba is Apollo's former lover and they had children together, all the more he sided with the Trojans

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mythology and Folklore! Your answer has a great start but we is it possible to elaborate a little bit further on this answer?